# Navigation controller and ScrollView Top Layout Guide Margin

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to align a "view" at the top of the screen but below the navigation bar. The view is inside a scrollview. The problem is that there is a gap at the top, where the top layout guide is not honored. I am writing this in Swift. Any solutions? I am attaching a photo of what's going on.

Basically, I want to remove the white part between the navigation controller and the blue background.

[image]

I also adding a snapshot of the constraints.

[image]

Comment: it should not be there. It's something wrong, check your interface builder, eventually put a screenshot with the xib. Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Did you unselect the `Adjust Scroll View Insets` on your navigation controller from the Storyboard?

Comment: if you are using autolayouts, kindly post a snapshot of constraints you applied

Comment: @PabloA. Yes, "Adjust Scroll View Insets" is disabled.

Comment: @Usama83, I have attached snapshot of the constraints.